# Double tap hololens using GestureRecogniser in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, hololens

I'm trying to implement both the tap and double tap gestures in the hololens. Each individual gesture works, however, when I double tap, it single taps also twice. I saw a few using timers to solve it, but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Since I'm using the GestureRecogniser, I have a callback method:

```
private void GestureRecognizer_TappedEvent(InteractionSourceKind source, int tapCount, Ray headRay)
    {

        switch (tapCount)
        {
            case 1:
                OnTap();
                break;
            case 2:
                OnDoubleTap();
                break;
        }

    }
```

Can I do anything here, or will I have to resort to having a separate script which checks on it's `Update` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a timer and after the 'double click speed' timer has expired I SingleTap or a second click is detected then I DoubleTap.

The down side is that the double tap takes longer than a double mouse click and therefore adds some delay into the single tap which I am not sure is a good experience.

This is slightly old, so I'm curious what you ended up doing.

Comment: I did end up using timers in the end, since I couldn't find a better way of doing it, unfortunately. I was hoping there was a better way of doing it, but it seems to be fairly standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid using a timer as the double tap gesture is recognizable.

```
void Start()
{
    // get a new gesture recognizer
    recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    // set up to receive both tap and double tap events
    recognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap | GestureSettings.DoubleTap);
    // see https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/VR.WSA.Input.GestureRecognizer.TappedEventDelegate.html 
    recognizer.TappedEvent += (source, tapCount, ray) =>
    {
        if (tapCount == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Tap");
        }
        else if (tapCount == 2)
        {
            Debug.Log("Double Tap");
        }
    };
    recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It basically calls it once with `tapCount` as 1, and then again with it as 2. So it doesn't bypass the first one. I mean, your code is pretty much identical to mine. I had already added the DoubleTap gesture setting.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still no complete (working) answer to this, and I couldn't find one elsewhere, here's how I fixed it. Similar to using a timer, but slightly nicer in my opinion.

```
const float DELAY = .5f;

void Start()
{
    recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();

    recognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap | GestureSettings.DoubleTap);
    recognizer.TappedEvent += (source, tapCount, ray) =>
    {
        if (tapCount == 1)
            Invoke("SingleTap", DELAY);
        else if (tapCount == 2)
        {
            CancelInvoke("SingleTap");
            DoubleTap();
        }
    };
}

void SingleTap()
{
    Debug.Log("Single Tap")
}

void DoubleTap()
{
    Debug.Log("Double Tap")
}
```

Note: I couldn't find the delay with which a double tap is recognised, so I assumed it is the Windows default of half a second.